# Open A File At a URL Created By URL.createObjectURL in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, html

So I have a Rails form with the following field:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'object_url'%>
```

And I have a URL created URL.createObjectURL and set to the hidden field value:

```
var url = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
$("#object_url").attr("value", url);
```

I am trying to open the file from `blob` in the controller with this (the_file is a Paperclip field):

```
unless params[:recorded_object_url].blank?
  @object.the_file = open(params[:object_url])
end
```

But I get this error when I submit the form:

```
Errno::ENOENT (No such file or directory - blob:http%3A//localhost%3A3000/2b68b5f2-0c92-4488-91b8-bee176afde1a):
```

Where "blob:http%3A//localhost...etc..." is the URL created by `createObjectURL` It seems like `open()` is failing for this file.

Is there a way to open a browser File API created file in Ruby? Does the file object not persist after the form submission?

Comment: try: `open(params[:object_url].split('blob:').join)` appended `blob:`to URL is causing the error.

Comment: That didn't seem to do it. Will open not handle something that starts with `blob:`. I wonder if the issue is around the persistence of the file itself after the form submit. Because I'm able to access the file via `url` in the page before I submit the form.